# How can I show custom fields in the loop only to specific user roles?

Tags: custom-field, loop

I've inserted this code in the loop (in single.php):

```
<span style="font-size:16px">
<strong>Currently reading:</strong> <?php the_field('book_name'); ?> (<?php the_field('book_year'); ?>)<br/>
<strong>Currently seeing:</strong> <?php the_field('movie_name'); ?>"><br/>
</span>
```

Anyway, that's only an example. It is successfully showing in the individual post.

How can I restrain that information to be shown only if a user is logged in with specific roles? (Author, editor and administrator).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`current_user_can()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/) and [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) to validate current user:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('role') ) : ?>
    <span style="font-size:16px">
    <strong>Currently reading:</strong> <?php the_field('book_name'); ?> (<?php the_field('book_year'); ?>)<br/>
    <strong>Currently seeing:</strong> <?php the_field('movie_name'); ?>"><br/>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Make sure to change `role` to your preference and take a look at [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) for more info.